# Missing assembly reference in App.xaml page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I cannot find my solution it says missing assembly reference on 
please explain in detail

```
      <Application.Resources>
    <converter:RssTextTrimmer xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS"
      x:Key="RssTextTrimmer" />
    <converter:ImageFromRssText xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS"
    x:Key="ImageFromRssText" />
        </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally that if you have open for first time a extern project that haven't build in your project you must rebuild or build it in your own computer. If this not resolve the problem, you must see if:

xlmns:converter="..." is correct. Are RssTextTrimmer, ImageFromRssText in the root folder?

greetings!